# How can I make the SVG color follow my CSS

Tags: css, svg

```xml
<svg width="19" height="18" viewBox="0 0 19 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="vuesax/linear/export">
<g id="export">
<g id="Vector">
<path d="M7.48999 4.87502L9.40999 2.95502L11.33 4.87502" fill="white"/>
<path d="M7.48999 4.87502L9.40999 2.95502L11.33 4.87502" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</g>
<path id="Vector_2" d="M9.40997 10.635V3.00751" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path id="Vector_3" d="M3.5 9C3.5 12.315 5.75 15 9.5 15C13.25 15 15.5 12.315 15.5 9" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I have tried putting the `fill=currentColor` and `stroke=currentColor`, but when I add the CSS to

```css
color: red;
fill: red;
stroke: red;
```

I added `<img src="sample.svg" class="svg-icon">`, and in my style.css I did `.svg-icon { color: red; fill: red; stroke: red; }`

It still stays black and the color is not changing. How can I fix this?

I'm looking to do something like adding the SVG in a CSS then calling the CSS class in a tag.

E.g.: in style.css `.icon { SVG }`, and then in HTML `<i class="icon"></i>`.

Comment: where do you add the CSS to? Please post reproducible code in the form of a [repro]. I cannot reproduce the issue you describing. if I add that CSS to either the SVg or the path it works as expected.

Comment: I added `<img src="sample.svg" class="svg-icon">`

then in my style.css i did 

```
.svg-icon {
    color: red;
    fill: red;
    stroke: red;
}
```

Comment: You can not format an SVG using "outside" styles, when you embed it as an `img`(or as an object, iframe, background image.) This will _only_ work, if you embed your SVG into the document by putting the full `<svg>...</svg>` code _directly_ into your HTML. https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#aa-the-problem-with-both-img-and-background-image

Comment: I wrote the [``<load-file> Web Component``](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) to load external SVGs, _inline_ them in the DOM, so you can apply CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the color of an SVG using CSS, you should not use a  tag to include the SVG in your HTML. Instead, you should directly include the SVG code within your HTML, and then apply the CSS to the SVG elements. Here's how you can do it

1. Include the SVG code directly within your HTML:

Apply CSS styles to the SVG elements directly. For example, if you want to change the fill and stroke colors of specific paths within the SVG, you can do it like this

By including the SVG directly in your HTML and applying CSS styles to the SVG elements, you can control the colors and other styles as desired. Using an  tag to include the SVG will not allow you to apply external CSS styles to the SVG's elements.

Comment: Hi ok got it. thanks for the info. Question is there a way to make it css like make the svg to be in a css class then i just call a tag with a class of that icon ?

E.g.:

style.css
.icon { SVG }

then in html <i class="icon"></i>

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <!-- CSS style which you must add into your code -->
    <style>
      #Vector,
      #Vector_2,
      #Vector_3 {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- Your SVG -->
    <svg width="19" height="18" viewBox="0 0 19 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g id="vuesax/linear/export">
        <g id="export">
          <g id="Vector">
            <path d="M7.48999 4.87502L9.40999 2.95502L11.33 4.87502" fill="white" />
            <path d="M7.48999 4.87502L9.40999 2.95502L11.33 4.87502" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
          </g>
          <path id="Vector_2" d="M9.40997 10.635V3.00751" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
          <path id="Vector_3" d="M3.5 9C3.5 12.315 5.75 15 9.5 15C13.25 15 15.5 12.315 15.5 9" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried not working

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: @JeremyCaney I did it. Thanks for the advice.